# ¿Por que print_r($arreglo) si funciona y echo $arreglo[0]; etc no funciona?

Tags: php

Bunas tardes, porque la funcion `print_r($arreglo);` muestra todo los valores de cada indice del arreglo y cuando se quiere hacer un echo `echo $arreglo[0];` no se puede. Para funciones futuras ocupare usar la funcion `echo()` dentro del HTML es por ello que necesito hacerlo usando la funcion `echo()` y no `var_dump();` o `print_r();` de ser imposible, ¿cual seria la forma de accesar a los indices del arreglo dentro del html?

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","capacitacion");
    $consulta = "SHOW TABLES FROM capacitacion";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if($resultado){
        $tablas = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado);
        print_r($tablas);
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Este codigo solo muestra errores sucedidos por la palabra Array:

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","capacitacion");
    $consulta = "SHOW TABLES FROM capacitacion";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if($resultado){
        $tablas = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado);
        echo $tablas[0];
        echo $tablas[1];
        echo $tablas[2];
        //etc..
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Si agregas una muestra de tus datos seguro alguien te puede ayudar mejor

Comment: Me parece que `mysqli_fetch_all` te mete los datos globales dentro de un arreglo, prueba a ponerlo así: `echo $tablas[0][0]; echo $tablas[0][1];` etc. O bien sacas los datos del índice `0` en una variable y luego usas esa variable: `$mData=$tablas[0];` y luego : `echo $mData[0]; echo $mData[1];` etc.

Comment: Okay, primero intente modificando el segundo indice del arreglo como por ejemplo ```echo $tablas[0][1];``` y asi sucesivamente pero no funciono, por lo que pense que a lo mejor si comnezaba cambiando el primer indice y dejando el segundo en cero podria funcionar asi, ```echo $tablas[1][0];``` etc, y asi si funciono. Nada mas que no se por que se hacen como si fueran arreglos bidimensionales para cada uno de los datos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega un pequeño fragmento del `print_r` para revisarlo. Puede que `fetch_all` te esté haciendo una especie de *both* (ambos), creando dos tipos de datos, uno asociativo y otro numérico. Habría que ver el Manual de PHP...

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => exa ) [1] => Array ( [0] => primer_examen ) [2] => Array ( [0] => trewtr ) [3] => Array ( [0] => slakjdf) )

Comment: Si te está devolviendo ambos. Ahora te lo explico en una respuesta.

Comment: Gerardo revisa mi respuesta editada. Tu consulta es algo particular, por tratarse de `SHOW TABLES`. Podrías leer los resultados usando un `foreach` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) dice esto:

> `mysqli_fetch_all()` consulta todas las filas y devuelve el resultado
>   en un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos.

Al no indicarle el *fetch style*  te está devolviendo los datos dos veces, en forma de array asociativo y de array numérico.

Añadido a eso, la consulta que intentas ejecutar es particular, porque no traería columnas fáciles de identificar, una forma de mostrar tu lista de tablas sería recorriendo los resultados en un bucle:

Así debería funcionar:

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","capacitacion");
    $consulta = "SHOW TABLES FROM capacitacion";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if($resultado){
        $tablas = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado, MYSQLI_NUM); #Seteamos fetch style
        foreach ($tablas as $row){
            echo $row[0].PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Si necesitas guardar la lista en otra variable, puedes llenar un array dentro del `foreach` para este tipo de consulta particular.

Answer (score -1):

es un arreglo de arreglos, la forma en que lo puedes consultar es:

```
echo $tablas[0][1];
echo $tablas[0][2];
echo $tablas[0][3];
```

Saludos,